# xpath issue (HtmlAgilityPack)

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-parsing

I have a "TR" node array. All I want is to get child "TD" tags of each its element.

I don't have any idea of how to do it.
Anyone knows?

Here's my code:

```
foreach (HtmlNode tr in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CustomerByLocation_ViewPanelStandAlone_ViewPanel_Grid_ctl01\"]/tr[position()>1]"))
{
    foreach (HtmlNode td in tr.SelectNodes("//td"))
    {
         w.WriteLine(td.InnerHtml);
    }
    w.WriteLine("***********************");
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but use single quotes within the string. That is what I always did.

Comment: @AlexHerrmann you need to use single quotes..Also check if `id` value is same as in the html

Comment: @AlexHerrmann, not every language uses single quotes like C/C++/Java, and I am 90% certain that XPath does not follow the C convention. Don't make such an overly-broad statement.

Comment: Yes, you were right. It is about xpath definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath "//" means "all nodes starting from root - so your second search `"//td"` ignores `tr` as parent and searches whole DOM anyway.

Most likely you are looking for just `"td"` (instead of `"//td"`).

Comment: No..the second //td won't search the whole dom

Comment: @Anirudh - what do you think it means than?